# How can I have one element align to the left and another one centered in Vaadin HorizontalLayout?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I wanna center my Label component in Horizontal Layout (I'm working on navigation bar) but I still want to have hamburger menu button aligned to the left side of the screen, 
[image: just like that]

I tried to use

```
navbar.setComponentAlignment(myLabel, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
```

on my Horizontal Layout but this don't work, it only center in verticaly,

[image: like this:]

What can I do to achive that?

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin Label is by default 100% wide, so you need to set its width to undefined to center it:

```
myLabel.setWidthUndefined();
```

Of course, your `HorizontalLayout` must be 100% wide (it's undefined by default).